# TypeScript Iterate JSON and put JSON elements

Tags: json, angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm new to TypeScript but what I want to do is fairly simple but the documentation doesn't seem to cover iteration over JSON. What I want to do is iterate over a JSON response array and put a JSON object into each JSON element. Here's the code I'm working with, the TypeScript evaluator in WebStorm is telling me that `speakerElement` is a string and not JSON so I can't use the `put` function.

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
   this.http.get('http://.staging.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/cr3ativspeaker')
   .map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log("the speaker data is : ", data);
  console.log("the speaker data is : ", JSON.stringify(data));
  //get each speakers image and append it to their data
  for(let speakerElement in <JSON>data) {

    this.http.get('http://.staging.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/cr3ativspeaker')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(response => {

       speakerElement.put("media_details", response.media_details);

      });

  }

  this.data = data;
  resolve(this.data);
});
});
```

Comment: if the json is in string form just use JSON.parse to build it into an object

Comment: try (<any>speakerElement).put("media...

Comment: `data` is no longer JSON when you get into the handler for `subscribe`. So, the first thing is to stop thing of JSON as anything special; it's just how the data gets from the service to your code. Once you call `res.json()` it's just JavaScript objects and arrays. With that out of the way, we can talk about what your data actually looks like. And for that we need you to [edit] your question to add a sample of the data you're getting from the first HTTP GET call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, Everyone thanks for the suggestion. I found the answer which required a very small change. I was using `in` in my `For Loop`. I needed to use `of`. The correct code is

```
 for(let speakerElement of data) {
            console.log("Speaker element",speakerElement);// element is JSON 

          }
```

Comment: Thanks! The use of "of" instead" of "in" threw me too so seeing this saved me some time.